# How to take the curl of a vector function involving hypergeometric functions?

Tags: special-functions, vector-calculus

I have a vector function involving a hypergeometric function as its inner constituent. I need to take the curl of this vector and when I do, *Mathematica* prompts this array of errors:

```
TensorRank::fscl: Nonscalar expression {0.6 -97.9987 I,0.6 +97.9987 I} encountered as an argument of numeric function HypergeometricPFQ.
TensorRank::fscl: Nonscalar expression {0.6 -97.9987 I,0.6 +97.9987 I} encountered as an argument of numeric function HypergeometricPFQ.
TensorRank::fscl: Nonscalar expression {0.6 -97.9987 I,0.6 +97.9987 I} encountered as an argument of numeric function HypergeometricPFQ.
General::stop: Further output of TensorRank::fscl will be suppressed during this calculation.
Symmetrize::fscl: Nonscalar expression {0.6 -97.9987 I,0.6 +97.9987 I} encountered as an argument of numeric function HypergeometricPFQ.
Symmetrize::fscl: Nonscalar expression {0.6 -97.9987 I,0.6 +97.9987 I} encountered as an argument of numeric function HypergeometricPFQ.
Symmetrize::fscl: Nonscalar expression {0.6 -97.9987 I,0.6 +97.9987 I} encountered as an argument of numeric function HypergeometricPFQ.
General::stop: Further output of Symmetrize::fscl will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

I tried differentiating `HypergeometricPFQ` functions with complex arguments and it does the operation readily. So the problem only arises when I'm taking the curl. I wonder what am I missing in my calculations?

Here's my code,

```
fun[z_] = (E^(-z))^2.*HypergeometricPFQ[{2. - I, 2. + 2.*I}, {2., 3. - 3.*I, 3 + I}, -2/E^z]
vector[x_, z_] = {E^(I*x)*fun[z], E^(I*x)*z, fun[z]}
Curl[vector[x, z], {x, y, z}]
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your data and code in your question, or we won’t be able to help.

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for letting me know. The code is now included.

Comment: If I copy your code in a fresh kernel I get a valid result: 

`{-E^(I x), -2. E^(
   I x) (E^-z)^2. HypergeometricPFQ[{2. - 1. I, 2. + 2. I}, {2., 
     3. - 3. I, 3 + I}, -2 E^-z] + (0.333333 + 0.333333 I) E^(
   I x - z) (E^-z)^2. HypergeometricPFQ[{3. - 1. I, 3. + 2. I}, {3., 
     4. - 3. I, 4 + I}, -2 E^-z], I E^(I x) z}`

Are you sure all the symbols that you are using are correctly defined?

Comment: @dpravos actually I got the same results but all the errors mentioned in the body text is generated beforehand. Since even in the case of encountering an error, Mathematica still cranks out some outputs (probably defective results), I thought maybe what I've got off the code wasn't correct.

Comment: I don't get any error message.

Comment: @dpravos It's a bit peculiar. I'm running the most recently released version of Mathematica. Have you tried the code through the same version?

Comment: No, sorry, I am working on Mathematica 11.0.1.0 for Mac OS X x86.

Comment: The code also executes without error messages in MM 10.4.1.0.  Perhaps this is a bug introduced in version 11.1.

Comment: I can confirm that I see similar errors in MMA 11.2 on Win7-64.

Comment: I can confirm that I see similar errors in MMA `11.3` on Win-8.1-64bit. Works fine on MMA `10.2.0`

Comment: Strange. Error message in version 11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite all the errors I get when I directly use Mathematica's built-in "Curl" operator, it still outputs an answer which totally matches that I get when taking the curl term by term (without using the Curl operator). 
So it appears that these error messages have nothing to do with the actual process of effecting the curl operator. However, I still don't know what sort of underlying malfunction happens.

```
FullSimplify[{-E^(I*x), -2.*E^(I*x)*(E^(-z))^2.*HypergeometricPFQ[{2. - 1.*I, 2. + 2.*I}, {2., 3. - 3.*I, 3 + I}, -2/E^z] + 
     (0.33333333333333337 + 0.33333333333333337*I)*E^(I*x - z)*(E^(-z))^2.*HypergeometricPFQ[{3. - 1.*I, 3. + 2.*I}, 
       {3., 4. - 3.*I, 4 + I}, -2/E^z], I*E^(I*x)*z} == {-E^(I*x), E^(I*x)*D[fun[z], z], E^(I*x)*I*z}]

True
```